# Weird behavior when subclassing Hash

Tags: ruby, subclass

I'm trying to subclass Ruby's `Hash` to introduce my own behavior when a specific key is accessed. This requires an additional parameter when constructing, so I have implemented my custom hash like so:

```
class PlayerCollection < Hash
    def new(server)
        @server_player = SpecialPlayer.new(server, "Server")
        super(nil)
    end

    def [](key)
        key == "Server" ? @server_player : super(key)
    end

    def []=(key, value)
        key == "Server" ? value : super(key, value)
    end
end
```

As you can see, I'm calling `super` with a value of `nil`, as I'd like my hash to return `nil` when the value is not found in the hash. However, my hash ends up returning the `server` object when the key is not found, as though I've created my hash with `Hash.new(server)`!

How can I avoid this behavior? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `PlayerCollection`, you should overwrite `Hash#initialize` rather than `Hash#new`.

That `new` is not called. It's the class method `Hash.new` (or `PlayerCollection.new`) which gets called.

Comment: OK, that's enough coffee for me for one day! I feel silly now D: